# Silverlight WP7 App pulling wrong content from XML file

Tags: xml, silverlight, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7

UPDATE:  I provided better context for the code which I was using to access the contents of the XML file.

I am making a Windows Phone 7 app in which I access an online XML file.  However, the way the file is structured is causing me to pull the wrong items from the file.

Here is the general structure of the file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<rss version="2.0">
<channel>
  <title>XML File Title</title>
  <link>http://www.url.com</link>
  <description>Description</description>
  <item>
     <title>Title of first item</title>
     <description>Description of first item</description>
  </item>
  <item>
     <title>Title of second item</title>
     <description>Description of second item</description>
  </item>
</channel>
```

My code is causing me to pull the title and description from the top of the file, instead of the title and description within each item.  Here's my code:

```
XElement xmlitem = XElement.Parse(e.Result);

        var list = new List<datainfoViewModel>();

        foreach (XElement item in xmlitem.Elements("channel"))

        {
            var title = item.Element("title").Value;
            var description = item.Element("description").Value;


            list.Add(new datainfoViewModel
            {
                Title = title,
                Description = description,
            });
```

I know what I'm doing wrong, I'm just not sure how to change the code to fix it.  Thanks in advance for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have tried changing:

```
foreach (XElement item in xmlitem.Elements("channel"))
```

to

```
foreach (XElement item in xmlitem.Element("channel").Elements("item"))
```

As your code is doing what you say is happening it loops through all the "channel" items which there is only one in your case, which has a description and title, however the one you want is an item, which is a child of channel.

Comment: Haha, brilliant!  I had tried something very very similar to this earlier but I just wasn't getting the syntax right.  Thanks for taking the time to help out a dope like me.

Comment: No problem when I first started using LINQ to XML I made similar mistakes myself until I got used to it!

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is to tunnel down (using LinqToXml), node by node to narrow the scope of your query until you are left with a collection of `item` elements. Now you can select the right values. Here's how I'd do it:

```
var xmlitem=
    XDocument.Parse(
        @"<?xml version=""1.0""?><rss version=""2.0""><channel>  <title>XML File Title</title>  <link>http://www.url.com</link>  <description>Description</description>  <item>     <title>Title of first item</title>     <description>Description of first item</description>  </item>  <item>     <title>Title of second item</title>     <description>Description of second item</description>  </item></channel></rss>"
    );
var list =
    xmlitem
        .Element("rss")
        .Element("channel")
        .Elements("item")
        .Select(e=>new datainfoViewModel
            {
                Title=e.Element("title").Value,
                Description=e.Element("description").Value
            }
        )
        .ToList();
```

Comment: I think this is putting me on the right track, but if you could look at the update I made regarding my code and tell me how to work this into it, that would be great.  Thanks!

Comment: Easy... no iteration required.

Answer (score 0):

Try your LINQ in the form used in this post.

[binding a Linq datasource to a listbox](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsphone7series/thread/0baf666f-5797-4917-9228-0a66dead8f72)

In place of "person", ask for "item".